# Avoid printing unicode replacement character in Java

Tags: java, unicode, character, replace

In Java, why does `Character.toString((char) 65533)` print out this symbol: � ?

I have a Java program which prints these characters all over the place. Its a big program. Any ideas on what I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Were are they coming from in the first place? Why are they in the strings you're printing? Please clarify this.

Comment: one place where they're coming from is rss feeds.
and probably from various other web services too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the most likely scenarios is that you are trying to read ISO-8859 data using the UTF-8 character set. If you come across a sequence of characters that is not valid UTF-8, then it will be replaced with the � symbol.

Check your input streams, and ensure that you read them using the correct character set.

Answer (score 8):

> In java, why does Character.toString((char) 65533) print out this symbol: � ?

Because exact this particular character **IS** associated with the particular [codepoint](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). It does *not* display a random character as you seem to think.

> I have a java program which prints these characters all over the place. Its a big program. Any ideas on what I can do to avoid this?

Your problem lies somewhere else. It at least boils down that you should set **every step** which involves `byte`-`char` conversions (storing text in file/db, reading text from file/db, manipulating text, transferring text, displaying text, etcetera) to use `UTF-8`.

Which catches my eye is the fact that Java does absolutely nothing special with `0xFFFD`, it just replaces uncovered chars by a question mark `?` and that while you keep insisting that `0xFFFD` comes from Java. I know that Firefox does exactly what you said, so are you maybe confusing "Firefox" with "Java"?

If this is true and you're actually talking about a Java webapplication, then you need to set at least the HTTP response encoding to `UTF-8`. You can do that by putting `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` in top of the JSP page in question. You may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful to get more background information and a detailed overview of all steps and solutions you need to apply to solve this "Unicode problem".

Answer (score 2):

There is no Unicode character U+FFFD. Hence, the code is logically incorrect. The intended use of the Unicode Replacement Symbol is to be substitued for bad input (such as `(char)65533`).

How to fix it: don't put junk in strings. Strings are for text. Bytes are for random binary data.

Comment: this one says there is...
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Comment: One can argue whether the value representin an "invalid input character" itself is a valid character. It is not a letter, not a digit, not punctuation, not a mathematical symbol, etc.

Comment: It's a "special" character. But since it even has a font representation I'd certainly call it a character, even if it is used as substitute. There are plenty unused code points, lets not confuse things further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you *want* it to do? If you're getting these characters "all over the place" I suspect you have bad data... it should be pretty rare that you receive data which can't be represented in Unicode.

How are you getting the data to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [primer on character encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).