# unidentified characters in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, cluster-computing, pi

I faced these strange abnormal characters when I was trying to calculate `PI` number in terminal over a Beowulf cluster.
how can I convert these characters into some legible characters?
it's interesting that when I make less processes , the result is normal .

[image]

Thanks in advance.
**edit:**

**This was done with mpich 1 and with 1000 processes over a 3-computer cluster.**

Comment: sth like this : #�@#�#�#�#�@#�#�#�#�@#�#�#�#�@#�#�#�#�@#�#�# #�@#�#


#�@#�#
      #�#�@#�#
              #�#�@#�#
                      #�#�@#�#
                              #�#�@#�#
                                      # #�@#�#

#�@#�##�#�@#�##�#�@#�##�#�@#�##�#�@#�## #�@#�����#����#����#@#�##
#�@#�##�#�@#�#r

#�@#�#r#�#�@#�#r#�#�@#�#r#�#�@#�#r#�#�@#�#r# #�@#�#r#

Answer (score 1):

Because the output has lots of [Unicode replacement characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), it looks as if the locale settings on your machine are not set to use UTF-8 encoding.

Of course, it could simply be from attempting to print *binary* data on the terminal.  But locale is a possibility.  In either case, the terminal is running with UTF-8 encoding and your output is not valid UTF-8 *text*.

Resetting the terminal will not be helpful; it is the application (or your use of it) which is the problem.

Further reading:

- [Overcoming frustration: Correctly using unicode in python2](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html)
- [Avoid printing unicode replacement character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832304/avoid-printing-unicode-replacement-character-in-java)